# Converting the data file from the source sheet into the target sheet format using python.

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

```
import pandas
data = pandas.read_csv("Source_Sheet.csv")
data1 = pandas.read_csv("Target sheet.csv")
#print(data.dtypes)

data1["permanent address"] = data["Permanent Address"]
data1["delhi address"] = data["Delhi Address"]


name_party_area = data["Name of Member \nParty \nConstituency(State)"].str.split('\n')
name = []
party = []
area = []
state = []
for n in name_party_area:
    name.append(n[0])

for p in name_party_area:
    party.append(p[1])

for a in name_party_area:
    try:
        temp = a[2]
        k = temp[0:temp.find("(")]
        area.append(k)
        l = temp[temp.find("(")+1:-1]
        state.append(l)
    except:
        pass

data1["name"] = pandas.Series(name)
data1["organisation"] = pandas.Series(party)
data1["Area"] = pandas.Series(area)
data1["State"] = pandas.Series(state)


email_phone = data["Email Address \nTelephone Nos."].str.split('\n')
#print(email_phone[0])
sansad_email = []
email = []
for item in email_phone:
    try:
        if "@" in item[0]:
            if "@sansad.nic.in" in item[0]:
                sansad_email.append(item[0])
                if "@" not in item[1]:
                    email.append("NA")
            else:
                email.append(item[0])
                sansad_email.append("NA")
        else:                            
            sansad_email.append("NA")    
            email.append("NA")                  

        if "@" in item[1]:
            email.append(item[1])
    except:
        pass 

number = data["Permanent Telephone No."]
nos = []
sec_nos = []
for num in number:
    try:
        d = num.rfind("(M)")
        g = num[d-11:d]
        nos.append(g)
    except:
        nos.append("NA")
    try:
        j = num.find("ax")
        h = num[j+5:j+18]
        sec_nos.append(h)
    except:
        sec_nos.append("NA")

data1["Mobile"] = pandas.Series(nos)
data1["Secondary phones"] = pandas.Series(sec_nos)

data1["email "] = pandas.Series(email)
data1["sansad email"] = pandas.Series(sansad_email)

data1.to_csv("Target_sheet.csv")
print(data1.shape)
```

This was my approach, but I do not get the expected results. Also, the output showed just 9 rows while it should have returned 403 rows. 
I have a problem extracting permanent mobile number and secondary mobile numbers.

The link to the csv files is - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pXXwE-QjmKc_PH8EFkH9ZhejwZc8QY6v

Comment: you can do str.split('\n', expand=True), which will put each item in the resulting list into its own column and save you the trouble of iterating through name_party_area

Comment: Thanks, @user3582076 but I am getting the expected output for that portion, I am having a problem separating the permanent mobile number and secondary numbers. Also, I do not get the expected results separating sansad_email and email. As for some entries, there is no sansad_email but 2 email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly, but this is my suggestion.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

data = pd.read_csv(r"../notebooks/Source Sheet.csv")
data.head()
```

[image]

```
data1 = pd.DataFrame(
    index = data.index,
    columns = ['name','organisation','Area','State','Mobile','Secondary 
    phones','email','sansad email','permanent address','delhi address']
)
data1.head()
```

[image]

```
# ADRESS
data1["permanent address"] = data["Permanent Address"]
data1["delhi address"] = data["Delhi Address"]

# NAME/ORG (AREA temp.)
data1[['name','organisation','Area']] = (data['Name of Member \nParty     
    \nConstituency(State)'].str.split('\n',1,expand=True).apply(
        {0: lambda x: x.str.split(',',1,expand=True),
         1: lambda x: x.str.replace('\\n','')}) )

# AREA/STATE
data1[['Area','State']] = (data1['Area'].str.replace('\)','')
    .str.split('\(',1,expand=True))

# E-MAILS
data1[['email','sansad email']] = (data['Email Address \nTelephone Nos.']
    .str.findall("([a-z0-9]+[\.'\-a-z0-9_]*[a-z0-9]+@[a-z0-9]+[\.'\-a-z0-9_]*[a-z0-9])").to_frame()
    .apply(
        {'Email Address \nTelephone Nos.':(lambda x: ', '.join(x) if type(x)==list else [])}
    ).iloc[:,0].str.split(',',1,expand=True)

# PHONE NUMBERS
def mobile(x):
if (type(x)==list):
    x = ' '.join(sorted(list(set(x))))
    return x if len(x.replace('(','').replace(')','').replace(' ',''))>8 else None
else:
    return None

def phone(x):
if type(x)==str:
    x = x.replace('(M)','').replace('\n','')
    x = re.sub(r'09[0-9]*','',x)
    x = x.rstrip(' ').rstrip(',')
    return x if not (x.strip(' ') in [',','']) else None
else:
    return None

data1['Mobile'] = (data['Permanent Telephone No.'].str.findall(
        "\([0-9]{1,4}\)|09[0-9]*").to_frame().applymap(mobile))
data1['Secondary phones'] = (data['Permanent Telephone No.'].map(phone).to_frame())

# FINAL RESULT
print(data1.shape)
data1.head()
```

[image]

#### [EDIT] Explanation to `mobile()` and `phone()` funtions:

Let's take a look at your original phone information:

```
>>> data['Permanent Telephone No.'].head()
    0    Tel : (0194) 2452540, 09018210000 (M)\nFax. (0...
    1    Tel : (02133) 235101, 09868180788 (M) \nFax : ...
    2                 0903799999 (M)\nFax : (033) 24999121
    3    Tel : (03220) 255599, 09434005207 (M) \nFax : ...
    4    Tel : (03220) 255067, 09434039494 (M)\nFax : (...
    5    Tels : (022) 28871042, 28863403 (R), 098681802...
    6                                 Tel : (079) 22504525
    7            Telefax : (0121) 2769955, 09412202623 (M)
    8           Tel : (07172) 251651\nFax : (07172) 254791
    9                                      09549477777 (M)
```

Instead of using (M) to identify the absolute mobile number location I searched for patterns using *regular expressions (regex)*. To do so, I supposed that all mobile numbers started with 09 (Is that correct?) and I also wanted to keep the local area code.

```
"\([0-9]{1,4}\)        -->>> Any sequence of up to 4 numbers inside ()
|                      -->>> `OR`: logical
09[0-9]*"              -->>> Numbers starting with 09NNNN...
```

So `str.findall()` finds all occurrences of that regex and returns they as list:

```
>>> data['Permanent Telephone No.'].str.findall("\([0-9]{1,4}\)|09[0-9]*")
    0    [(0194), 09018210000, (0194)]
    1                    [09868180788]
    2              [0903799999, (033)]
    3                    [09434005207]
    4                    [09434039494]
    5             [(022), 09868180266]
    6                          [(079)]
    7            [(0121), 09412202623]
    8                               []
    9                    [09549477777]
```

But the final `data1['Mobile']` have to be a string, not a list. So, I defined the `mobile()` function to that. To avoid duplicates occurrences I used `(list(set(x))` and `sorted()` to ensure that the "code area" was the placed before the cell number:

```
>>> x = ['(0194)', '09018210000', '(0194)']
>>> x = ' '.join(sorted(list(set(x))))
>>> print(x)
    (0194) 09018210000
```

The `phone()` function is simpler.

1. It's clean "(M)" and "\n" chars
2. Replaces all occurrences of mobile phone patterns (`re.sub(r'09[0-9]*','',x)`)
3. Cleanup the right side, stripping white spaces and ","

Comment: Hey thanks, this works but can you please explain the 'phone' and 'mobile' functions and how are you calling them.